# Como eu consigo pegar o máximo e o mínimo de uma consulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
select DATEDIFF("D",DtVencimento,DtBaixa) as atraso
  from Entrada 
 where Id='1' and DtEmissao >='01/01/2020' 
   and DtEmissao <='01/12/2020' 
   and ((VlBaixado is not null and VlBaixado != 0) 
   and DtBaixa is not null) 
   and DATEDIFF("D",DtVencimento,DtBaixa) < 0;
```

Quando ela me retornar mais de uma linha eu preciso identificar o maior e o menor valor. Por exemplo, no resultado abaixo:

| atraso |
| --- |
| -6 |
| -10 |
| -20 |

Eu preciso identificar o menor (`-20`) e o maior (`-6`) valor.

Alguém pode me ajudar a retornar esses valores numa consulta no SQL Server?

Comment: Vc quer que os valores sejam retornados em linhas separadas?

Comment: Não necessariamente, eu só gostaria de conseguir fazer uma com os valores máximo e mínimo. Eu não estou sabendo como fazer.

Comment: Se pode ser na mesma linha então você pode utilizar as funções Min e Max

Comment: Obrigado @imex eu já tentei usar, mas da forma como eu faço não estava resolvendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar CTE:

```
WITH foo(atraso) AS 
(select DATEDIFF("D",DtVencimento,DtBaixa) as atraso 
 from Entrada 
 where Id='1'
   and DtEmissao >='01/01/2020'
   and DtEmissao <='01/12/2020' 
   and ((VlBaixado is not null and VlBaixado != 0) 
   and DtBaixa is not null) 
   and DATEDIFF("D",DtVencimento,DtBaixa) < 0)
   
SELECT min(atraso), max(atraso) FROM foo;
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante, eu não sabia fazer dessa forma. Resolveu aqui para o que eu preciso.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT max(atraso) Min,
       min(atraso) Max
from (
       select DATEDIFF("D",DtVencimento,DtBaixa) as atraso
         from Entrada 
        where Id='1' and DtEmissao >='01/01/2020' 
          and DtEmissao <='01/12/2020' 
          and ((VlBaixado is not null and VlBaixado != 0) 
          and DtBaixa is not null) 
          and DATEDIFF("D",DtVencimento,DtBaixa) < 0;
     ) Tab
```

Comment: Opa, eu estava fazendo desse jeito, só que não estava dando certo porque eu não estava colocando nome no from. :-) Obrigado.